# Baggage allowance

Tags: luggage, brazil

Im traveling to Brazil next month and an very confused about baggage allowance, my tickets were purchased in Feb and I'm not sure if im allowed 2 23 kg bags or one, the latam information is very confusing.

Comment: Yeah it is confusing... where are you flying from/to? Do you have this information on the ticket? When flying Brazil - somewhere - Brazil you have 2x23kg for sure, but somewhere - Brazil - somewhere probably not.

Comment: What company are you flying with? Economy or business class? What does your ticket say?

Comment: @HenricF LATAM is an airline.

Comment: Im flying from Dublin, changing  in Heathrow with British airways, from there to Brazil with Latam airlines, the BA information is very clear but the Latam does not make any sense , it is telling me several different amounts. Im economy. I have no ticket yet

Comment: @liz, It depends on where you fly from. Without that, nobody can answer it.

Comment: @liz what do you mean you don't have the ticket yet? In the question you said that you've purchased it in February

Comment: Sorry I was thinking as the ticket as a  physical thing, but  email/eticket  is not clear , the BA part is perfecty clear but the latam one is not.

Comment: @Kuba didn't know that, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: If you bought in Feb, you are in the under the old law. Maybe, 2x32kg.

Comment: @MarcelP. Thanks , I think that is what Im allowed but they make it very difficult to understand

Comment: I sure that it was allowed 2x32KG for Europe airplanes tickets bought before March, 15th. After that, each company can create their rules.

Comment: We need a copy of your e-ticket to answer this question. Closing until it's uploaded.